# Why does my .find() function keep throwing up an error?

Tags: python, text-files

i want to try to open up a file, find the index of a particular string (S_N) then seek the position and write something underneath.

i am using the code...

```
C1 = open("Class 1.txt", "a")
pos = C1.find(S_N)
C1.seek(pos)
C1.write(correct)
```

and every time i use it, python throws up this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eddie\Documents\HOMEWORK!!!!\11c\Computing Science\controlled assessment help\task3\task 3 official.py", line 41, in <module>
    pos = C1.find(S_N)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find'
```

WHY DOES THIS NOT WORK????

Comment: Well, because `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'find'`, what is `S_N`? What is that file content?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search directly through a file for a String; you must first convert to a string. Also, you are opening the file in `a` mode, which is write-only, so try something like this:

```
C1 = open("Class1.txt","r")
dataList = C1.readlines()
data = ""
for line in dataList:
    data += line
C1.close()

# do stuff with data, which is a string
```

---

Other Notes:

I do not recommend having a `space` in your file name; rename it to `Class.txt` as in my example.

To `.find(something)`, `something` must be a string, like: `data.find("S_N")`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having spaces in file names. Why would there be?

Comment: It's more confusing when dealing with command line, but you don't have to.

Comment: If you're on the command line, just put the file name in quotes, or escape the spaces (on POSIX systems). I just don't understand why you'd even bother telling someone to do this. We're not using DOS anymore...

Comment: Like I said, you don't have to...